Why does journalctl only show logs from previous 2 days?
On 22.04 LTS if I use journalctl to view the logs, I can only see entries from 48 hours ago (and while less important, journalctl --list-boots only lists the current boot).
Here's what I've checked (numbered so comments can reference):
Settings

In journald.conf: These are all set to the Ubuntu standard
defaults (see below).

Nothing in logrotate.conf or logrotate.d is set to below 4 weeks
(other than rsyslog which is 7 days).

No systemd timers or cron jobs (either in /etc/cron* or crontabs)
are set to truncate the journal (grep -r journal /etc/cron*)


Disk space

Journald will use up to 4Gb or 10% of disk space by default. On the
partition /var is on, I have ~30G available.

journalctl --disk-usage shows ~800-850G in use.

The journald.conf file is set to Storage=auto, but since
/var/log/journal exists (and is populated), that means it's saving the journal to disk ("persistent"). I have set it to "persistent" explicitly and reloaded the systemd unit but it makes no difference.

Perhaps there was some transient disk space issue that made
journald truncate, but I waited some time and it didn't come back.


Other

journalctl --verify reports no issues.

Performing a sync followed by a flush makes no change.


Comparison
I have another nearly identical machine which logs back several months (and has less disk space available).
How can I configure the journal so that I can see log entries from dates earlier than 48 hours?  The machine is a production server and I would rather not schedule down time for what might be a risky operation to delete the journal and re-set it.
~$ systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/journald.conf

[Journal]
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitIntervalSec=30s
#RateLimitBurst=10000
#SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
#ReadKMsg=yes
#Audit=no


Maybe there's something in your systemd-tmpfiles config (systemd-tmpfiles --cat-config) that's cleaning / removing the file?

I can't see anything in that which could be implicated :-(

@amar Thanks, but that just talks about the data storage, not how to see that data past 48 hours.

@amar No. But I have other logs that go back over 6 weeks.

@amar I don't have any cron or timers set up to do that, not have I run that command (which I guess just sets the logs to 2d at that point, but not permanently).

Archived and active journals take up 896.0M in the file system.
0 ea490d60d2884c668ea2b666be0c5458 Sat 2024-06-15 16:35:40 UTC—Mon 2024-06-17 17:03:51 UTC
A whole lot of "PASS" messages.

do not know if that is your problem but wort checking see the last message in page 2 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230625&p=2

No such file on my system.

And no folder called journal.conf?

locate  journal.conf only brings up /usr/lib/sysusers.d/systemd-journal.conf which isn't relevant.

I Think your journal is acting accordingly to the defaults it was installed https://serverfault.com/questions/809093/how-do-view-older-journalctl-logs-after-a-rotation-maybe see the message from jdf, and the comment under it, this may help https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/optimize-journalctl-to-save-server-disk-space-in-linux

I look at that, but another server has 16G on / and logs back to Feb 03.  This one has 29G on / and logs back to Jun 16. Both have identical configs.

dev/xvda1       54G   44G   11G  81% / That is what you should look at

It would be a good idea to check both servers filestructures in what we have discussed and also here /run/log/journal

dev/xvda1 is 45% now and has been lower recently.

An avenue to consider, see if any user has put a cron job effecting journalctl. https://cronitor.io/guides/five-places-for-cron-jobs

The setting #Storage=auto is disabled with a # in your /etc/systemd/journald.conf file. Anyway, it will not use more than 10% of the filesystems and is capped at 4GB. Maybe your logs grow too fast because of some service misbehaving and you can't see older entries getting deleted. Have you checked the current total size with journalctl --disk-usage to start with?
EDIT after the various updates in the question:
I have actually one of my 22.04 machines that has the "same" behaviour. Indeed, it would show only the last boot. There can be a number of reasons for this as explained here: How to find previous boot log after Ubuntu 16.04+ restarts? . On the affected machine, I uncommented Storage=persistent in /etc/systemd/journald.conf and let it reste a day doing 2 reboots. I know do have the last 3 boots properly shown in journalctl --list-boots. I'll leave it a few more day to make sure but you might want to try this as well. This behaviour might be the result of an upgraded machine vs. a fresh install and maybe that explains the difference between your machines.

Thanks. The man page says '"auto" behaves like "persistent" if the /var/log/journal directory exists', which in my case it does. I have set it to "persistent" and reloaded the unit but it makes no difference. The journal is using 888.0M, I have 29G available on the partition with /var. Will update my question to clarify.

You're welcome. With the new data added to your question based on my answer it becomes a bit clearer (your df -h yesterday now removed showed your system almost full if I remember well). And between your edit and your comment above there is already new journal data added (from 888 to 896). If you now leave it running for a day or so, can you then check if you have more data as wanted?

Unfortunately, the log (journalctl | head) still starts at "Jun 19 00:00:32" (it's now Jun 20). The partition that /var is on wasn't almost full BTW, that was /home/mail.

That sounds strange indeed and other than checking any particular logrotate settings ( /etc/logrotate.conf ) you might have, running a bit out of clues here...

For me, the proposed solution in the EDIT of my answer does work on the machine I was able to reproduce this. That is a few days ago and the head stays at it's original starting point and the past boots all get properly listed. So for me the Storage=persistent did actually make a difference even though it sounds contradictory with the man page. I will check in a few days if this now stays current and history remains available but it looks promising.
